# Limit number of characters in reactjs

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I have a input box where serial number has to be filled in. The max character is 32 so the texting should stop when number of character reaches to 32. I tried to do in 2 ways but both ways are not working. The first way i tried to update the state with custom function where some pattern is defined. Second way i tried to pass the pattern in Textfield component as a props. The component is of react-mdl and it shows the error when the pattern mismatch.

**Second way that i tried to change the pattern that is passed in the Textfield component as a prop by default**

```
<Textfield
    onChange={(event)=> {this.handleInputChange(event)}}
    pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?"
    error="Input is not a number!"
    label="Device Serial Number"
    floatingLabel
/>
```

to

```
<Textfield
    onChange={(event)=> {this.handleInputChange(event)}}
    pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]{6,32})?"
    error="Input is not a number!"
    label="Device Serial Number"
    floatingLabel
/>
```

**first way(with first Textfield example)**

```
const extract = (str, pattern) => (str.match(pattern) || []).pop() || '';

const extractPattern = (str) => extract(str, "-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?");

const limitLength = (str, length) => str.substring(0, length);


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {max_char:32, limit:{}};
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }


  handleChange(charLength){
      console.log('charLength',charLength);
      this.setState({
        max_char:32 - charLength.length,
        limit:limitLength(extractPattern(charLength), 32),
      });
      console.log('charLength', charLength);
      // console.log('limitLength', this.state.limit);
  }
```

Comment: why don't you check for length inside the function and if it's bigger than 32 then don't add anymore characters to the input.

Comment: If the component uses a regular HTML input field, why not set a maxLength on the input field instead of calling a function to check the length of the text within it every single time the input is changed?

Comment: I am using react-mdl Textfield component.

Answer (score 0):

Using props set the **maxLength** attribute in your textArea. I mean some constant value `this.props.customLength=32.` 
Also providing Validation in state is not recommended. 
your state should have as minimum data as possible.

Comment: I am using react-mdl Textfield component not textarea. Can you place the props that you have written based on my code?

Comment: Than probably you have to customize your textField Library According to you logic : https://github.com/tleunen/react-mdl/blob/master/src/Textfieldimp.js , you can see that implicitly is uses textarea in it, so you can apply logic inside it . May be you can update "inputProps" to achieve your behaviour. Hope that will work